# Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, Could not transform tcdl file

Tags: 2011

Whenever I push any JavaScript or certain HTML markup `(<sup>®</sup> etc.)`, even after  replacing  such markup  with  their alternative code (e.g. `&lt;sup&gt;&#174;&lt;sup/&gt;`), I get stuck due to  below error:

> Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, Could not transform tcdl
>   file /opt/apps/lisdl/XYZ/temp/Zip/tcm_0-299595-66560

Always everything seems fine in page preview and even rendering phase also completed successfully.

Most of the times I did not get enough pointers in the "Transaction detail" information to fix this error and to fix it  either I have to spend a lot of time through several hit and try or have to change the implementation  approach .

Could somebody explore the generic tips to debug such errors, stuff or markup which is not acceptable by deployer and possible causes of such errors over here.

**NOTE:** I am not looking for the solution of above mentioned error example. So please share your experience to debug and avoid this error here only.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure it's only when specific markup exists in your package that's already a good starting point.

This is what I would do:

- Get a snapshot of the package at every stage through deployment:

  - c:\temp (by default) will have a copy of the package the publisher sends to transport
  - [Deployer incoming folder] will have a copy of the package received by the deployer
  - [Deployer incoming folder]\Failed will have a copy of the package after processing (and failure)

Look inside the packages for any special markup that may have been added as part of the publishing process. Maybe you have some TBB that adds *magic* to your output.

- Disable TCDL transformation and see what happens. Easiest is to change your target language (in the publication target) to none. If it publishes correctly then you know for sure this is an issue with TCDL transformation and not a different exception being masked by the TCDL transformers

Hopefully this will bring you some more clues into what is happening and you can investigate those. Good luck.